# Creating this shape in CSS3 as a drop down div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create something that looks like this:

[image: dropdown]

The problem is I think it would be best to keep it inside of one div since the drop down has an inner shadow and drop shadow.

Thanks in advance and please let me know if you need any more detail on the problem.

This is what I have so far:

### CSS

```
.rectangle {
    background: #1f8dda;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, #1f8dda 0%, #114dbc 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, #1f8dda 0%, #114dbc 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(270deg, #1f8dda 0%, #114dbc 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #1f8dda 0%, #114dbc 100%);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #000000;
    -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #000000;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 145px;
    height: 138px;
}
```

I also created a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/yHy5n/

Comment: I updated with some css and a fiddle. The problem is I want to extend the lower part but keep the gradient and dropshadow/innershadow constant throughout the drop down object.

Comment: It isn't possible to do this in one shape. You may have to cheat a bit and have the bit behind the top nav a solid colour and then have the gradient behind the subnav start with that colour. `box-shadow` could also be tweaked so it's only on the bottom edge of the subnav.

Comment: why not use an image? / where is that example from?

Comment: @Eric Are you livin' in the 1990s?

Comment: @Eric It was a comp I created in photoshop with the help of a tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the fact that you menustructure looks quite weird, here is a quick sketch I did for you as a starting point: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fzy6U/1/)**
It is not meant to be the complete solution but rather an idea you can work with.

Given the markup below, the basic idea is to style the list elements of the main list (`h2`) and the sublists separately and make the gradients have a smooth transition.

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>HOME</li>
    <li class="active"><h2>DUNGEONS PIECES</h2>
    <ul class="subnav">
        <li>Floor<span class="count">123</span></li>
        <li>Walls<span class="count">54</span></li>
        <li>Sets<span class="count">7</span></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.active {
    background: #1f8dda;
    /* ... */
}
.active h2{
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #1f8dda 34%, #228fdd 100%);
    /* ...                                                    /\ */
}            /*            gradient transition   --------------- */
.active ul { /*                                  \/              */
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #228fdd 34%, #114dbc 100%);
    /* ... */
}
```

Also most of your compatibility css isn't needed anymore - take a look at:

[Gradients](http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient)
[Box-shadow](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow)

Comment: This is what I was trying to explain :)

Comment: This helps a ton. (Sorry for not getting back to you sooner) Thank you for this awesome answer. It put a lot into perspective after taking a long break from front end development.